# Populating Dropdownlist With Displayed Gridview Column Names

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a situation, where I need to display the column names of a GridView in a DropDownList, and then as the user selects the column names in the dropdownlist determine if that column is a numeric or a string value.  Does anyone have any idea on how I would do this?  I'm not even sure where to start.

Here is the code for my GridView and DataSource if it helps.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="intBatchID" 
            AllowPaging="True" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="NOCTS" 
            BorderStyle="Solid" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#990033" Width="1000px" 
            DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="intBatchID" HeaderText="Batch ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="TestPage1.aspx?intBatchID={0}" DataTextField="intBatchID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="vcharName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="vcharName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dtmScheduled" HeaderText="Date Scheduled" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="dtmScheduled" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="intBatchPriorityLevel" 
                    HeaderText="Priority Level" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="intBatchPriorityLevel" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" PageButtonCount="4" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="Next" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=TestEntities" DefaultContainerName="TestEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="tbl_Batch"
    Select="it.[intBatchID], it.[vcharName], it.[dtmScheduled], it.[intBatchPriorityLevel]"
    OrderBy="it.[intBatchID]">   
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if it is one time thing it is much easier just hardcode that dropdown.

Alternatively you can go this way:

- [GridView.Columns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - will give you collection of columns which you can filter on some conditions , in your case I expect to filter them by being BoundField
- Use [GetView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.getview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to get  [EntityDataSourceView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasourceview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from [EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- You can use [EntityDataSourceView.GetViewSchema Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasourceview.getviewschema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to get DataTable
- Using columns from GridView you will find columns in DataTable and find their types

add references:

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Data;
```

Here is short snippet:

```
        var gvColumns = GridView1.Columns;
        var viewName = ((IDataSource)EntityDataSource1).GetViewNames().OfType<string>().First();

        var view = (EntityDataSourceView)((IDataSource)EntityDataSource1).GetView(viewName);
        var schema = view.GetViewSchema();
        var dsColumns = schema.Columns;
        var dvColumnsDict = gvColumns.OfType<BoundField>().ToDictionary(a => a.DataField);

        // ddlNames  is your ddl
        foreach (DataColumn c in dsColumns)
        {
            if (dvColumnsDict.ContainsKey(c.ColumnName))
            {
                var li = new ListItem(string.Format("{0}: {1}", c.ColumnName, c.DataType), c.ColumnName);
                ddlColumns.Items.Add(li);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I apologize I'm not as accomplished programmer as you are.  Obviously I'm newer at this than you are.  I'm getting a lot of errors in your code.  I'm not really sure how to make it work.

Comment: Is dvColumns is a variable?  I'm getting on GetViewNames() and GetView() that they are inaccessable due to their protection level.  Is that due to missing namespace?

Comment: I'm getting identifier expected at the end of this line if (dvColumnsDict.ContainsKey(c.))

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the column names and their data types, you can store them in hidden fields and use them to populate your dropdown list.

Or make a list on the server side. A list of objects with name and type properties. Get all the names and set it as datasource for the dropdown. In OnSelectedIndexChanged event, go to your list( it can be stored in session viewstate or hidden field)  And find the corresponding data type.

```
public class ColumnDetail 
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Create a list

```
List<ColumnDetail> columnDetails = new List<ColumnDetail>();
```

Add your details to this list. Save this list in viewstate.

```
ColumnDetailsDropdown.datasource = columnDetail.Select(cd => cd.Name).ToList();

    ColumnDetailsDropdown_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string type = columnDetails.where(cd => cd.Name ==( (Dropdown) sender).SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Can't put in more detail. I am using my phone.

Comment: How does it connect to the GridView to get the column names?

Comment: Are columns in your gridview dynamic?

Comment: They won't change once they are populated from the EntityDataSource.

Comment: Column names are your Header Text which does not depend on EntitySource. And if you already know the type of your columns you can add them directly to the list without connecting to the GridView.